# How to determine the properties of a self intersecting curve (parametric functions) : number of loops and of passages through a point?

Tags: curves, parametric, parametrization, intersection-theory

Let's define a parametric vector $(f(t),g(t))$.

If there a way to  determinate how many times this function will come back to a certain point ?

For instance here is the plot of  $(f(x),g(x))=\left(-2 x-\log (1-x)+0.1 \log (x)-0.9,\log (1 - x)+x^2+0.9 x\right)$ in the interval $x\in[0,0.7]$

[image]

And we count one loop, and one intersection in this loop.

Or if you look at  $(f(x),g(x))=(x \sin(x),x \cos(x))$ in the interval $x\in[-10,10]$ you observe 3 points of intersection.

[image]

However for the function : $(f(x),g(x))=(\sin(x), x \cos(x))$, there are two points of intersection, but each point counts many passages :

[image]

So my question is wether there is a way to determine wether there exists a loop and one many time is the curve going through the intersection in an interval.

The last functions are easier to handle but I'm looking for a general approach and criteria, for more complex functions like the first one.
The final result could be gotten numerically. But I don't know what is the best way to pose the problem, and I assume there exists already some litterature about it.

Any  references are welcome.

**EDIT :**

One trivial necessary condition is the following : there must exist 1 inflexion point for each of the two functions.

Comment: I'd expect there not to be a lot done on this, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong. However, if you restrict to polynomial or rational functions, you could implicitize the parameterization and easily find singular points of the resulting algebraic curve.